# Is casting sender in event handler always necessary?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

Consider the following event handler

```
Private Sub ProfileSelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProfileSelectCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    ProfilesComboBox.Enabled = ProfileSelectCheckBox.Checked
End Sub
```

In this handler, I don't use `sender` at all, however I have seen numerous people talking about the pattern of casting `sender`. In my case, I would end up with some awkward code since the handler didn't pass me an object reference to `ProfilesComboBox`.

```
ProfilesComboBox.Enabled = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked
```

If this handler were added for another `CheckBox` at runtime, I would end up with some broken code with or without the cast, leading me to believe it's better to limit the scope of the handler's definition to inside a method anyway to hide it from outside, but maybe that's bit off-topic.

In this simple example, I don't see the need for the cast. My question is, is this frowned upon / bad practice, or just simple enough to let it pass?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its a requirement to use sender at all, let alone cast it.  If you wanted a generic event handlers casting might help, but for something as specific as your sample its not useful.

However probably a better way to link the controls would be to use the MVP pattern, which would make the behavior in your sample more testable.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Private Sub Yadayada(...) Handles ProfileSelectCheckBox.CheckedChanged
```

No, it is already obvious who the sender is going to be.  It is, without a doubt, the ProfileSelectCheckBox.  Because that's the control you named in the *Handles* clause.  No point in casting the sender, might as well use ProfileSelectCheckBox directly in your code.

That's the obvious use for the event handler you wrote, many event handlers are like that.  But it isn't limited to that.  The *Handles* keyword accepts more than one event source.  You can also write it like this:

```
Private Sub Yadayada(...) Handles ProfileSelectCheckBox.CheckedChanged, _
                                  UserSelectCheckBox.CheckedChanged
```

Which is an event handler for **two** controls that have a CheckChanged event handler.  Clearly you are now more interested in the *sender* argument, it allows you to tell the difference between the ProfileSelectCheckBox and the UserSelectCheckBox firing the same CheckChanged event.

You can extend this endlessly, adding more and more event sources to the *Handles* clause.  Or you can use AddHandler statement in your code to do it without the Handles keyword.

The distinguishing feature here is that none of this happens when you use the Winforms designer.  It happens when you write your own code instead of leaving it up to the code generator.  That's a mental leap, it is a very important one.  It makes you a *real* programmer that no longer abides with a robot generating code for you.

Congratulations and welcome to the party.